# Combining images side by side with overlays in beamer

Tags: beamer, overlays, includegraphics, png

I have [left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppIBj.jpg) and [right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM2Qf.jpg) images. I want to place them side by side and overlay them by clicking next in the presentation. The left pictures should change with every click and the right pictures would be nice to overlay with every click, so the old data still is shown in a weaker colour density. I thought smth like this:

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{\textheight}
        \begin{figure}
            \only<1>
    {%
      \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{left1.png}%
    }%
             \only<2>
    {%
      \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{left2.png}%
    }%
            \only<3>
    {%
      \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{left3.png}%
    }%
\end{figure}
\end{overlayarea}    
\end{minipage}%


\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{\textheight}
    \begin{figure}
                 \only<4>
        {%
                 \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{right1.png}%
        }%
                 \only<5>
        {%
                 \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{right2.png}%
        }%
                 \only<6>
        {%
                 \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{right3.png}%
        }%
\end{figure}
\end{overlayarea}    
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

But it doesnt work yet. Maybe somebody has some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Tasks}



\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{\textheight}
\begin{figure}  

    \raggedright
    \only<1>
    {%
      \includegraphics[scale=0.9]{left1.png}%
    }% 
    \only<2>
    {%
      \includegraphics[scale=0.9]{left2.png}%
    }%
    \only<3>
    {%
      \includegraphics[scale=0.9]{left3.png}%
    }%
    
    
    \vspace*{-5.75cm}
    
    \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{\textheight}

    \raggedleft

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \only<1> {% 
    \node (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{right1.png}};%
    }%
    \only<2> {%
    \node (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{right1.png}};%
    \node [opacity=0.8] (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{right2.png}};%
    }%
    \only<3> {%
    \node (0,0) [opacity=0.5] {\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{right1.png}};%
    }%
    \only<3> {%
    \node (0,0) [opacity=0.5] {\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{right2.png}};%
    }%
    \only<3> {%
    \node [opacity=0.7] (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{right3.png}};%
    }%
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{overlayarea}   

\end{figure}
\end{overlayarea}      
\end{frame}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Positioning on the same horizontal level works so far just with `\vspace*`

Opacity has to be selected so far manually which can be tough with many images. Maybe somebody has an idea how just the last image gets high opacity and all images before
have low opacity and are still visible.